# Self Join in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a ticket table with create_time column. When a ticket is created, one row is inserted in the table, create_time column inserted with create time. And when the ticket is closed, another row is inserted in the table, but now create_time column gets closed time of the ticket. Please help me in the query in which i can get the Ticket_Number, Create_time as Create Time, Create_time as closed time in one row. 
Means one ticket should appear once along with 2 create_time column.

Say i have following data:-

```
Ticket_Number Create_Time 
123           09-12-2018 
123           10-12-2018
```

I want output as single line. Output means Ticket should appear only once and create_time column should come twice one with Create Date and one with close date.

```
Ticket_Number Create_Time Create_Time 
123           09-12-2018  10-12-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect the close time to always come after the create time, so the creation time is the minimum value of the column `create_time` and the close time is the maximum value for that column.

So you need a simple group by query:

```
select ticket_number, 
       min(create_time) as create_time, 
       max(create_time) as close_time
from the_table
group by ticket_number;
```